# nonhomogenous reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have a problem figuring out how to solve this problem.  It is $$([D^2]+[2D]+[1])y=([e^x-1])^{-2}.$$
I am more worried in solving for V.  I used $y=v[e^{-x}]$. 
I got $$v''[e^{-x}]=([e^x]-1)^{-2}.$$  Now I have to do a double integral. On the first integral I will get a natural log of $-\ln[(e^x)-1]$, but how do I get the second integral?  The answer should be $$[e^{-x}](c_1 + c_2 \, x \cdot -\ln([e^{-x}]-1).$$  I am not sure how.  My professor told me that I already integrated twice, but not sure how.

Comment: oh thanks!! for editing it :p

Comment: hmmmm i am not sure how to integrate the first integral you setted up.  I did v"e^-x=(e^x-1)^-2.  then i i divided both sides by e^-x and i get on the right side [e^x]([e^x]-1)^[-2].  then i use u subsitution.  and i get integral of u^-2.  which equals to the log of ln[u].  but thats still the first integral.  i dont understand how to integrate a log!!

Comment: aaa right i remember that from calculus 2.  I could do it that way, thanks!!!  but is there any other way that you could make things simpler and less time consuming during a test?  my profesor used u subsitution, and used (e^x-1) for u.  thats for the first derivative, but for the second?

Comment: thanks!!  i will do that, differential equations is getting rough!!

Answer (score 0):

You properly arrived to $$v''=\frac{e^x}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}$$ Integrating once gives $$v'=-\frac{1}{e^x-1}+c_1$$ So $$v=c_2+c_1x-\int\frac{dx}{e^x-1}$$  For the last integral, change variable $$x^x=t \implies x=\log(t)\implies dx=\frac {dt}t$$ which makes $$J=\int\frac{dx}{e^x-1}=\int\frac{dt}{(t-1) t}=\int\left(\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt=\log(t-1)-\log(t)$$ Back to $x$ $$J=\log(e^x-1)-\log(e^x)=\log(e^x-1)-x$$ All of this makes $$v=c_2+c_1x-\log(e^x-1)+x=c_2+c_3x-\log(e^x-1)$$ If you prefer to see $e^{-x}$, just rewrite $$e^x-1=e^x(1-e^{-x})\implies \log(e^x-1)=x+\log(1-e^{-x})$$

Comment: but how do you get to that first integral? on my first integral i got a integral of -1/u , so making it a natural log.  can you show me how you get -1/(e^x -1)?